# e4 RCP synchronous processing of events

Tags: events, e4

I have got multiple instances of a class which listen to a certain event.

```
@Inject
@Optional
private final void doSomething(@UIEventTopic(Events.A) Object object) {
    //do something
}
```

My question is: if I use the synchronous method `IEventBroker.send`, will this method *reliably* wait until all of the listening objects are done? My tests indicate yes, but I would just like to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaDoc for `IEventBroker.send` says:

> Publish event synchronously (the method does not return until the
>   event is processed).

Internally the event broker uses the OSGi `EventAdmin.sendEvent` method, which says:

> Initiate synchronous delivery of an event. This method does not return
>   to the caller until delivery of the event is completed.

So, Yes synchronous delivery is guaranteed.